# plot a single row of time series data in scala spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have time-series data that is stored as different columns for different time points, the structure is like following:

```scala
-----------------------
|t1 | t2 |t3 |t4 | t5 |
-----------------------
| 1 |  2 | 3 | 4 |  6 |
-----------------------
```

In total, I have 100 columns corresponding to 100 time points, How can I plot it as a line chart in scala spark?

Comment: You can use the several visualization libraries like https://cibotech.github.io/evilplot/plot-catalog.html

Comment: I can't find what I need in the link you provided, could you please be more specific about this?